# How to get $_POST which has blank parameters

Tags: symfony-services

I understand that as per new rules, post request in drupal should be replaced with

```
$stack->getCurrentRequest()->request;
```

But I need to know what is the replacement for $_POST which does not have any parameters. Should we use

```
$stack->getCurrentRequest()->request->get();
```

or

```
$stack->getCurrentRequest()->request->all();
```

?

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is according to the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) an associative array.

`$stack->getCurrentRequest()->request` is a [Symfony parameter bag](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21ParameterBag.php/class/ParameterBag/9.0.x) representing this array.

[ParameterBag::all()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21ParameterBag.php/function/ParameterBag%3A%3Aall/9.0.x) would then be a method to get the entire array.